# Error al traer informacion de la BD la fecha y meterla a un input

Tags: php, html

Mi pregunta esta dirigida a lo siguiente:
necesito traer la fecha que tengo en los registros y modificarla y que me guarde la nueva fecha, pero al querer traer la fecha me dice que es falso, trate con una sentencia en sql pero me marca error en la sentencia sqlsrv_fecth_array, les pongo el codigo espero y me puedan ayudar

```
<?php
$serverName = 'localhost';  
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"cccc", "UID"=>"gggg", "PWD"=>"vos");
/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */  
try  
{  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);  
    //echo 'Conectado';
}  
catch(Exception $e)  
{   
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );   
}  

    $fecha = ""; 
    $nombreQuejoso = ""; 
    $apellidoQuejoso = ""; 
    $servidorPublico = "";
    $tipoAutoridad = "";
    $nacionalidad= "";
    $ocupacion="";
    $domicilio="";
    $localidad="";
    $municipio="";
    $telefono="";
    $celular="";
    $observaciones="";
    $fechaNacimiento="";

$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tExpedientes WHERE IdExpediente='" .$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY fecha DESC";
    $version = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($version)) {
        $nombreQuejoso = $row["QuejosoNombre"]; //
        $apellidoQuejoso = $row["QuejosoApellidos"]; //
        $servidorPublico = $row["ServidorPublico"]; //
        $tipoAutoridad = $row["TipoAutoridad"]; //
        $sql1 = "SELECT date_Format(Fecha,'%d.%m.%Y HH:ii:ss') as NewFecha FROM tExpedientes WHERE IdExpedientes=Fecha ORDER BY Fecha DESC"; //
        $fecha1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1);
        **$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($fecha1);**
        $fecha = $row('NewFecha');
        var_dump($fecha);
    }
```

Aqui es donde lo quiero meter, puede ser que yo este mal pero aun no se como hacerlo.

```
    <legend>Cambio de Fecha</legend>

    <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly" size="18" value="<?php echo ($fecha); ?>"><br>
```

Comment: esta parte suena totalmente mal: WHERE IdExpedientes=Fecha

Comment: Entonces seria quitarlo al igual ya lo estoy declarando en la parte de arriba.

Comment: Cuando `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` devuelve falso significa que ha habido un error: _If a row of data is retrieved, an array is returned. If there are no more rows to retrieve, null is returned. **If an error occurs, false is returned**._ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-fetch-array Yo para depurar hago print_r de mi $sql para ver si se está construyendo bien.

Comment: Hola me manda esto "bool(false)" en la sentencia de sql

Comment: es q esta mal.. probaste el query en la base de datos? fijate en lo que te señale arriba...

Comment: si es  lo que estoy revisando deja hago lo que me comentas y te comento muchas gracias deja intento

Comment: al hacer el query me dice que 'date_Format' is not a recognized built-in function name. me supongo que es por la version del sql porque uso mylittleadmin

Comment: ok, arregla el query y fijate si despues la pregunta sigue sirviendo, o cierrala y has otra...

Comment: ok deja intento te agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que el formato en el que tratas de asignar sea de la siguiente forma `YYYY-MM-DD`

Ejemplo:

```
<input type="date" name="fecha" value="2017-03-30">
```

Comment: ok entonces para mostrarla en value no necesariamente tiene que ser directamente la variable o me equivoco.

Comment: Eso si ya depende de como quieras asignarlo en el input, puede ser directamente asi como lo haces actualmente o bien jquery o javascript con esto me refiero a ajax, y algo que debes de tener en cuenta por el momento solo el input de tipo date acepta unicamente el formato que mencione en la respuesta el datetime no lo soportan unicamente opera y safari. o pueder usar plugins para usar el formato datetime

Comment: Gracias voy a cambiar algo de codigo y en cuanto tengo algo comento como me va.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos, tienes un error de sintaxis al utilizar:

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($version)) {
}
```

ya que la que es utilizada por sqlsrv es diferente a la de mysql por ejemplo, y se aplicaria de esta manera:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $version, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
}
```

Te dejo el link del manual de php referente a sqlsrv: https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

me fue posible dar con la respuesta, a lo mejor no es lo mas optimo pero me funciona les dejo como lo resolvi.

```
$version = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($version)) { 
    $nombreQuejoso = $row["QuejosoNombre"]; //
    $apellidoQuejoso = $row["QuejosoApellidos"]; //
    $servidorPublico = $row["ServidorPublico"]; //
    $tipoAutoridad = $row["TipoAutoridad"]; //

    **$fecha = date_format($row["Fecha"],'d/m/Y h:i');**
```

solamente tenia que darle el formato ya que al traerlo me lo marcaba como un objeto, espero y le funcione a alguien mas, les agradezco mucho su ayuda.